# Filtering passwords out TeamCity logs

Tags: teamcity

If one of my TeamCity jobs fails it might have an error message like:

```
Timeout when requesting: https://<myuser>_<mypassword>.someserver.com
```

It's hard to suppress this since these errors can be raised deep in some dependency.

The logs are visible to a lot of people and I'd rather not have the passwords in there. Is there some way to configure a filter / grep / sed command to remove this kind of information?

Answer (score 0):

A proper way is to avoid using URLs with passwords. If this is a TeamCity VCS root, then the password should be provided in the dedicated password field. In this case TeamCity will not log it.

Comment: That’s not really feasible. Of course I can fix the one issue that appeared now, but I can not foresee every possible issue . I am look for was to filter the output so that certain patterns can’t appear